# GetTempFileName creates an empty file

Tags: delphi, winapi

i'm not sure if i'm the first one to notice this, but (lol, it's kinda funny...) when ever i make a call (i debugged the application to verify this) GetTempFileName (from the Windows.pas unit), it creates an empty (0 byte) file in my D:\ (no idea why there) drive...

i have 2 logical drives... C:\ (Primary) and D:\ (Logical), now this ONLY happens if i call it when the first argument (arg0) is just a dot ('.'), which is weird to me that it creates it in D:\ since parent directory is 2 dots ('..').

anyways, a dummy bypass for this is to just delete the newely created file... -_-, all i need is the file NAME, not the file system itself...

Edit1: My question is, why is this happening ? and is there a way to avoid the call from creating a new empty file ?

```
// Creates a name for a temporary file.
Function GetTempFileName(const ext: string): string;
var
  // This buffer should be MAX_PATH characters to accommodate the path plus the terminating null character.
  lpTempFileName: Array[0..MAX_PATH] of char;
begin
  // If uUnique is zero, GetTempFileName creates an empty file and closes it.
  // If uUnique is not zero, you must create the file yourself. Only a file name is created
  Windows.GetTempFileName('.', nil, 0, lpTempFileName);
  DeleteFile(lpTempFileName); // delete created file
  Result := ChangeFileExt(lpTempFileName, ext);
  Delete(Result, 1, 2); // ".\"
end;
```

Comment: How else can Windows ensure that nobody else uses that particular name between your call to `GetTempFileName` and the time that you actually create the file? (Yes, there are other ways, but they require more coding). Granted, chances of a collision are small, but they are real.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

***Why does GetTempFileName function create new empty file ?***

It's in the [`GetTempFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364991%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function description (emphasized by me):

> Creates a name for a temporary file. **If a unique file name is
>   generated, an empty file is created** and the handle to it is
>   released; otherwise, only a file name is generated.

---

***How to avoid creating the new file when using GetTempFileName function ?***

Either you can't let the function generate a unique file name (which creates an empty file) or just delete that created empty file after the [`GetTempFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364991%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function returns. From the reference (emphasized by me):

> Temporary files whose names have been created by this function **are
>   not automatically deleted. To delete these files call DeleteFile**.

Comment: yes, i saw this, but if in the uUnique i enter some random hardcoded string (just for testing) it does not generate a unique file name anymore... so i leave it empty to make it unique all the time.

Comment: You might also consider  Use System.IOUtils.TPath.GetGUIDFileName

Generates a new GUID that can be used as a unique file name.

Call GetGUIDFileName to generate a new GUID suitable as a unique name for a file or directory. GetGUIDFileName only generates a file name and does not create a real file.

Comment: Just a word of warning for this approach. From time to time an antivirus (or other application) will pick up the file to scan it in between GetTempFileName and the delete. This will result in the deletion failing because the file is in use by another process.